# Redirect local ip to public ip?

Tags: apache, centos, openstack, openstack-horizon

I have installed, open stack when I run locally 192.168.1.66 it show the dashboard of the open stack, but when I access it through public it display the default page of Apache. I am using centos 7.0 minimal. How I redirect the local IP to public IP so that it open the open stack dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like nothing is happening between that instance of Apache and your OpenStack Horizon dashboard. You can add a new vhost in Apache and make a simple reverse proxy. Let's say `/etc/httpd/conf.d/openstack.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

# You can set here your domain name (if you have one), your public IP address
# or just leave it like this, just as a placeholder:
server_name _ 

ProxyPass "/"  "http://192.168.1.66/"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://192.168.1.66/"

</VirtualHost>
```

Then make sure at least `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` modules are enabled. You can check this by running:

```
httpd -M |grep -i proxy
```

In case they are not, go enable them in the `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf` file (by uncommenting the corresponding `# LoadModule` lines).

Also I would recommend disabling default virtualhost, just in case.